# Java - JsonWriter deprecated

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq, deprecated

I am sending a string array with RabbitMQ and JsonWriter

```
mychannel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_SERVER, null, new JSONWriter().write(mystringarraylist.toArray(new String[0])).getBytes());
```

It works but my IDE warns me `JSONWriter` is deprecated.

What is the clean way to do this ?

Comment: Use `JSONStringer` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know the `JsonWriter` is deprecate
The documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/json/JSONWriter.html) says to use the `JSONStringer` instead which can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/json/JSONStringer.html)

Comment: I found JSONStringer in ``org.apache.wicket`` and ``org.json``. Both looks fine so i will try one. Thx.

Comment: whatever suits you mate, keep going!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an up-to-date library to handle json? Personally i like Google Gson which is open source under Apache2. You can get it from maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson or github directly.

The rabbitmq has nothing to do with the warning by the way.